# Подключение AVC клиента к веб аппликейшну

Tags: amazon-web-services

Вопрос по Amazon Vendor Central. Разрабатываем приложение для вендоров, где будут выводиться данные по аккаунту AVC. Однако пользователь приложения при регистрации не должен вводить никакие ключи, кроме стандартной регистрации и только нажимать кнопку "Даю согласие на подключение моего AVC аккаунта к данному приложению"  и все необходимые данные  из SP API отобразились в нашем приложении. Возможно ли это ?

Comment: Добро пожаловать на сайт Аленка, 
пожалуйста ознакомьтесь с сылками: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic